# Given observable of booleans, derive observable that reverts to false after one second

Tags: .net, linq, system.reactive, observable

I have an observable of booleans `IObservable<bool>`. I would like to derive a new observable similar to the old one but with extra falses inserted one second after each true value.

For example if the original were

```
time  value
   0  false
   2  true
   5  true
   8  false
```

The new observable would be

```
time  value
   0  false
   2  true
   3  false
   5  true
   6  false
   8  false
```

Can you help?

---

Edit: Here's an example to test your solutions

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
  .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
  .Select(x => x % 3 != 0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can't you just create a delayed task that creates the desired collection based on the original collection?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen go on

Comment: Do you want to change the original collection or create a new collection based on the original? In any case, I would imagine that you could simply do Task.Delay followed by a continuation that either updates the original or creates a new collection.

Comment: I prefer Paul's `SelectMany` to the more intuitive `Merge` here as it instrincally has a single source subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
someBoolObservable.SelectMany(x =>
    Observable.Merge(
        Observable.Return(x), 
        x ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => false) : Observable.Empty<bool>()));
```

Comment: Hey Paul, check my edit? I think 'Interval' should be 'Timer'. As per my comments in the question, I prefer this approach. +1

Comment: I want the one where it produces a single value after a certain amount of time and completes, i can never remember which of the 5045x overloads that is

Comment: :) Interval is always periodic, Timer with one arg or one arg + scheduler is the single event flavour.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var booleanOb = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => x % 3 != 0).Take(4);
    var onlyFalseAfterTrue = booleanOb.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Where(x => x).Select(x => false);

    var merged = booleanOb.Merge(onlyFalseAfterTrue);

    using (merged.Timestamp().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", x.Timestamp, x.Value)))
    {
        merged.Wait();
    }
}
```